# Customizing QHeaderView resize handle

Tags: css, qt, customization, qheaderview

I use the cleanlooks style for my application which fits best the look and feel I want.

The annoying thing a stumbled on is that the QHeaderView (horizontal header of a QTableWidget for instance)
doesn't paint the resize handle between sections when running uner an Unix host.

what I want:
[image: windows screenshot]

what I get:
[image: unix screenshot]

I started to search a solution using style sheets but it seems there is no way to control the handle rendering.

Do I have to play with borders style ?
Is there anything obvious thing I am missing?

I don't want to subclass QHeaderView or QStyle for such a little (trivial ?) problem.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I finally found a solution based on Css and borders. I'll give it as soon as I can reply to my own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what i found so far:

```
QHeaderView::section:horizontal{
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-left-color: white;
    border-right-color: darkgray; 
    border-right-width: 1px;
}
QHeaderView::section:horizontal:first{
    border-left-color: darkgray;
}
```

which gives this result:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Could you also accept the answer if it is indeed the correct solution to your problem?

Comment: The solution needs to be improved but that's a start. I can't accept my own response for the moment, must wait tomorrow.